# Jquery highlight words in editable div

Tags: jquery

I have an editable div and would like to highlight (apply a css class) to certain words WHILE the user is still typing in the div.

How would I do this using Jquery?

I tried using the `div.html().replace()` etc but it replaces it and then moves the cursor all the way back to the beginning.

Comment: Where are those certain words stored? In an array?

Comment: OK, I'm working on a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the html for the editable div directly will cause problems - when you save, you won't be able to tell the difference between a change made by the user and one made by the highlighting script.

However, you can have the user edit a plain text element while making it look like they are editing the highlighted element. Add a second div on top of your editable div with the style pointer-events: none and a transparent background. As long as both elements have the same font size, you will be editing the plain text version but seeing the colors from the highlighted version.

If the font size is fixed you can go a step further and use a textarea instead of an editable div. I used this approach to get a syntax highlighting editor working on iPad, which doesn't support inline HTML editing.